# Using Spring @Profile to load log4j2 xml configuration instead of maven <profile>

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j2

Currently I am loading my log4j2 configuration using maven like this

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/env-dev</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/env-test</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prd</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/env-prd</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

[image]

But this requires me to build a new war for each environment, which I would like to avoid. Is there a way for me to use the Spring @Profile annotation to load the log4j2 config instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried with log4j2 but I believe you can provide the configuration file location using the property `logging.config`.

As an example :-

In `application-dev.properties` file place the below content. This profile can be activated by using -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

`logging.config=/env-test/log4j2.xml`

In `application-prd.properties` file place the below content. This profile can be activated by using -Dspring.profiles.active=prd

`logging.config=/env-prd/log4j2.xml`

Place both the configuration files in src/main/resources directory.

NOTE: If using YAML it is more convenient as these can be placed in a single configuration file, Separating the documents using `---`.

Comment: logging.config=classpath:env-dev/log4j2.xml , worked for me. the file would be in src/main/resouces/env-dev/log4j2.xml